# Modifying a thesis class file

Tags: page-breaking, titles, document-classes

A friend of mine gave me a class file he had used for his dissertation, which he submitted this spring.  This is a class file he wrote; it was not provided by the university.

Between spring & summer, the university changed the requirements for a dissertation slightly, so that now the signatures of the committee belong on the title page, whereas before they were two separate pages.  I tried editing the `.cls` file so that it would combine the two into one page, but when I compile it, I get the two separate pages I got before.  I'd like to know how to fix the `.cls` file so that there's no page break between the two.

Here's what the `.cls` file was before I changed it:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\def\fileversion{v.1.0}\def\filedate{2011/20/04}
\ProvidesClass{uathesis}[\filedate\space\fileversion\space%
Provides the format required by the Graduate School for dissertations]

\DeclareOption{10pt}{\PassOptionsToClass{10pt}{report}}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\PassOptionsToClass{11pt}{report}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\PassOptionsToClass{12pt}{report}}
\DeclareOption{draft}{\PassOptionsToClass{draft}{report}}
\DeclareOption{final}{\PassOptionsToClass{final}{report}}
\DeclareOption{fleqno}{\PassOptionsToClass{fleqno}{report}}
\DeclareOption{leqno}{\PassOptionsToClass{leqno}{report}}
\DeclareOption{openany}{\PassOptionsToClass{openany}{report}}
\DeclareOption{openbib}{\PassOptionsToClass{openbib}{report}}
\DeclareOption{openright}{\PassOptionsToClass{openright}{report}}
\DeclareOption{oneside}{\PassOptionsToClass{oneside}{report}}
\DeclareOption{twoside}{\PassOptionsToClass{twoside}{report}}

\ProcessOptions

\LoadClass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}[1996/10/31]

\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}

\if@twoside
  \def\ps@headings{%
      \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
      \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
      \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
      \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
      \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
            \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
        \fi
        ##1}}{}}%
    \def\sectionmark##1{%
      \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
          \thesection. \ %
        \fi
        ##1}}}}
\else
  \def\ps@headings{%
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty
    \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
    \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
      \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
            \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
        \fi
        ##1}}}}
\fi

\DeclareOption{final}{%
 \ifpdf
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \pdfpagewidth=8.5in
    \pdfpageheight=11in}
  \fi
  \doublespacing
 }

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
%%  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \normalsize \centering \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 10\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \normalsize \bfseries \centering \MakeUppercase{#1}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
  }}
\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
                 \else
                   \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
                   \@afterheading
                 \fi}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
%%  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \normalsize \bfseries \centering \MakeUppercase{#1}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
  }}
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\ExecuteOptions{final}
\ProcessOptions

\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
{\singlespacing
\chapter*{\bibname}
    \@mkboth{\bibname}{\bibname}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}%
  \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
  {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
    \leftmargin\labelwidth
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
    \@openbib@code
    \usecounter{enumiv}%
    \let\p@enumiv\@empty
    \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
  \sloppy
  \clubpenalty4000
  \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
  \widowpenalty4000%
  \sfcode`\.\@m}
{\def\@noitemerr
  {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  \endlist}

\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
  \hbox{}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \newpage
  \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}

\newif\if@mainmatter \@mainmattertrue

\newcommand\frontmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
 \@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{roman}}
\newcommand\mainmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
 \@mainmattertrue
  \pagenumbering{arabic}}
\newcommand\backmatter{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \@mainmatterfalse}

\renewcommand*{\title}[1]{\def\ua@title{#1}}
\newcommand{\department}[1]{\def\ua@dept{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\author}[1]{\def\ua@author{#1}}
\newcommand{\director}[1]{\def\ua@director{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\month}[1]{\def\ua@month{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\year}[1]{\def\ua@year{#1}}
\newcommand{\previous}[1]{\def\ua@preved{#1}}
\title{The title}
\department{Mathematics}
\author{A.U.~Thor}
\director{The director}
\month{April/July/November}
\year{2011}
\previous{}

\def\halftitlepage{%
  \addtocounter{page}{-1}
  {\singlespacing
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{-1in}
    \vfill
    \begin{center}
      \ua@title
    \end{center}
    \vfill\eject
  }
}

\def\titlepage{%
  {\singlespacing
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{1in}
    \begin{center}
      \ua@title
      \vfill
      A dissertation submitted in partial fulfillment\\
      of the requirements for the degree of\\
      Doctor of Philosophy in \ua@dept
      \vfill
      By
      \vfill
      \ua@author\\
      \ua@preved\\
      \vspace*{1in}
      \ua@month~\ua@year\\
      University of Arkansas
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{1in}\eject
  }
}

\newcommand{\committeemember}[1]{%
\par
\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
\vspace*{.5in}
\hrulefill\\
#1
\end{minipage}\par
}

\def\duplicationrelease{%
  \chapter*{Dissertation Duplication Release}
  {\singlespacing
    \raggedright
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    I hereby authorize the University of Arkansas Libraries to
    duplicate this dissertation when needed for research and/or
    scholarship.

    \vspace*{.5in}
    \noindent
    Agreed\qquad
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
      \hrulefill\\
      \ua@author
    \end{minipage}
  }
}


\newenvironment{committee}
{\singlespacing
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \parindent=0pt
  This dissertation is approved for recommendation\\
  to the Graduate Council\\[.5in]
  Dissertation Director:
  \committeemember{\ua@director}
  \vspace*{.5in}
  Dissertation Committee:  
}
{\vfill\eject}

\setlength{\textheight}{9in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.525in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.025in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}

%% \CharacterTable
%%  {Upper-case    \A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H\I\J\K\L\M\N\O\P\Q\R\S\T\U\V\W\X\Y\Z
%%   Lower-case    \a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z
%%   Digits        \0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9
%%   Exclamation   \!     Double quote  \"     Hash (number) \#
%%   Dollar        \$     Percent       \%     Ampersand     \&
%%   Acute accent  \'     Left paren    \(     Right paren   \)
%%   Asterisk      \*     Plus          \+     Comma         \,
%%   Minus         \-     Point         \.     Solidus       \/
%%   Colon         \:     Semicolon     \;     Less than     \<
%%   Equals        \=     Greater than  \>     Question mark \?
%%   Commercial at \@     Left bracket  \[     Backslash     \\
%%   Right bracket \]     Circumflex    \^     Underscore    \_
%%   Grave accent  \`     Left brace    \{     Vertical bar  \|
%%   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}
%%
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `uathesis.cls'.
```

I removed the `\newenvironment{committee}` section and replaced the `\def{titlepage}` section with the following:

```
\def\titlepage{%
  {\singlespacing
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \parindent=0pt
    \vspace*{1in}
    \begin{center}
      \ua@title
      \vfill
      A dissertation submitted in partial fulfillment\\
      of the requirements for the degree of\\
      Doctor of Philosophy in \ua@dept
      \vfill
      By
      \vfill
      \ua@author\\
      \ua@preved\\
      \vspace*{1in}
      \ua@month~\ua@year\\
      University of Arkansas
    \end{center}
    \vfill
    This dissertation is approved for recommendation\\
    to the Graduate Council.\\[.5in]
    Dissertation Director:
    \committeemember{\ua@director}
    \vspace*{.5in}
    Dissertation Committee:  
    \committeemember{Dr. First Member}
    \committeemember{Dr. Second Member}
    \vspace*{1in}\eject
  }
}
```

Previously, the main `.tex` document contained the following:

```
\halftitlepage
\titlepage

\include{abstract}

\begin{committee}
\committeemember{Dr. First Member}
\committeemember{Dr. Second Member}
\end{committee}

\duplicationrelease
```

but I commented out the 4 lines from `\begin{committee}` to `\end{committee}`.  I can't see what in the `.cls` file is causing the page break between "University of Arkansas" and "This dissertation is approved...".  (I know that adding the names of the committee members inside the class file isn't ideal, but I'm not giving this to anyone else to use, and I just need to get this finished so I can submit it.)  How can I eliminate that page break?

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out.  Removing the `\vspace*{1in}` from near the top of the title page definition fixed it.  I guess there simply wasn't enough room for all of it on one page before I did that.